# JMeter - what is the default connect and response timeout for HTTP request

Tags: jmeter

What is the default connect and response timeout for HTTP request in Jmeter?

I didn't change any settings in `jmeter.properties` file.

[image]

```
# set the socket timeout (or use the parameter http.socket.timeout)
# for AJP Sampler implementation.
# Value is in milliseconds
#httpclient.timeout=0
# 0 == no timeout

# Idle connection timeout (Milliseconds) to apply if the server does not send
# Keep-Alive headers (default 0)
# Set this > 0 to compensate for servers that don't send a Keep-Alive header
# If <= 0, idle timeout will only apply if the server sends a Keep-Alive header
#httpclient4.idletimeout=0

# Polling to see if process has finished its work, used when a timeout is configured on sampler
#os_sampler.poll_for_timeout=100
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/) [source code](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.java#L819):

```
public int getConnectTimeout() {
    return getPropertyAsInt(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 0);
}

public void setResponseTimeout(String value) {
    setProperty(RESPONSE_TIMEOUT, value, "");
}

public int getResponseTimeout() {
    return getPropertyAsInt(RESPONSE_TIMEOUT, 0);
}
```

The default value is `0` which means "no timeout" therefore JMeter will wait for connection/response forever. So to be on the safe side I would recommend defining reasonable timeouts using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)